# How to let an integer maps to a class definition in C++?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++03

I have some classes:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Something() = 0;
}

class A : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Something() { /*...*/ }
    void SpecialActionForA();
}

class B : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void Something() { /*...*/ }
    void SpecialActionForB();
}
```

and an array:

```
Base* MyMembers[2];
MyMembers[0] = new A;
MyMembers[1] = new B;
```

and I want to do:

```
A* pointer_to_a = Get(0);
B* pointer_to_b = Get(1);
```

Is there any good way to implement this `Get()` function?

---

My solution is:

```
template <typename T>
T* Get(int index)
{
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(MyMembers[index]);
}
```

But first thing is that I have to write

```
A* pointer_to_a = Get<A>(0)
```

Which requires an additional `<A>`;

Second thing is that if somehow the `new` is screwed up like:

```
MyMembers[0] = new B;
```

Then the `Get()` is failed.
What I want is something like an automatic mechanism which can maps index 0 to A.

---

Extra details:
Actually I have `80` different classes derived from `Base` (They are my User Interfaces),
and my need is to get the real classes (the real UIs) to do things.

The functions I need to use are the above `SpecialActionForA()`...etc.

The `Something()` is also used, but is in the initialization stage of these UIs, or something managed by the UI manager system.

Comment: Why don't you simply work through the base class interface, i.e., `Base *Get(int index)`?  `Base` defines the virtual method, so your calls will work polymorphically.  `Base *a = Get(0); a->Something() // calls A::Something`

Comment: Hi: Because actually I have 80 different classes derived from `Base`, and my need is to get the real classes to do things.

Comment: If you really want the index zero to be an A, and this is always the case then use a tuple, this gives you type safety and std::get<0>.

Comment: Alternatively you could maintain a map from ints to typeids and then assert your assumptions.

Comment: @Skeen That sounds great, any reference to how to do it? I just cant figure out the keywords!! Thanks!!

Comment: @Skeen Sounds like I need a map of <int, typeid>. But how can I deduce `A` from the typeid?

Comment: @Marson: Which of my comments are you referring to?

Comment: @Marson: Check factory pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: @Skeen Actually both? But I havent google the tuple thing (am going to do it right now). What I want to do is an automatic mapping when I do `MyMembers[0] = new A`, then this 0 => A relationship is constructed somewhere (maybe in a map, or tuple, like u said). So when I call `Get(0)` then this mapping is automatically deduced.

Comment: @Marson: You can't typeid is a runtime construct while the type A is a compile time construct.

Comment: @Skeen Grrrr so my need is impossible in C++? (P.S. I can only use C++03, tuple is C++11, too bad :(

Comment: @Manson: you can certainly achieve this, however your assignment will return a new class, with templates to indicate this mapping, which will then need to be used for future processing, however brancing code will cause issues using this approach.

Comment: @Manson: The simplest solution is to have your Get method, take both an index and a variable (where the result is saved to) and then have the compiler do deductionon on the variables type, and then do the dynamic_cast, and asserting that it succeeds (that is assert that the type in the array, equals what you passed in as variable).

Comment: @Manson: you should consider this, if you can map indexes to types at compile time, then you can get your errors at compile time, otherwise you'll get your errors at runtime. - in C++03 you'll most likely have to aim for runtime assertions.

Comment: @Manson: Actually you might be looking for closed algebraic datatypes, these will allow you to assign whatever you want to it, and the internal state will keep track of which type is held, think of it as a type safe union. Boost offers this as boost::variant, you'll simply pass around the variant untill you need type knowledge in which case you can do a visitor, type matching or a get.

Comment: @Skeen Ok thanks! I'll take some time digesting what you said, thank you very much!

Comment: @Marson: Have a look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading of function works by looking up the argument list. It is not possible to understand what kind of the value you want by judging only the return type. Thus compiler forces you to give extra detail to instantiate the template. So your options are:

```
Base *Get(int N) {
    return MyMembers[N];
}
```

or

```
A *GetA(int N) {
   return MyMembers[N];
}
B *GetB(int N) {
   return MyMembers[N];
}
```

or

```
template <typename T> void Get(int N, T *&item) {
   item = (T*)MyMembers[N];
}
A* pointer_to_a; 
B* pointer_to_b; 
Get(0, pointer_to_a);
Get(1, pointer_to_b);
```

or your own

```
template <typename T>
T* Get(int index)
{
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(MyMembers[index]);
}
```

Comment: @Marson: The third solution is actually quite applicable if you ask me, just get rid of that c_style_cast and replace it with a `dynamic_cast` as in the fourth suggestion, and remember to check the return value against nullptr, in case the container actually didn't contain what you thought. Note: Using the third approach instead off the fourth allows the compiler to do template type deduction.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `unknown* Get(int)` in principle as it will require two or more functions having the same name but differing only by return value. C++ explicitly prohibits this.

The closest function that you can get is this:

```
template <typename T> T* Get() {
  static T* instance = new T;
  return instance;
}
```

so you will be able to use it as:

```
A *a = Get<A>(); 
B *b = Get<B>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your usage scenario, it'll be a bit hard to provide a useful answer, but I actually do believe what you want is type matching. So what you do is that you pass your variables around as Base pointers until I you actually need to know the concrete underlying type, at this point you do a matching on the underlying type of your base pointer. This is works pretty much alike a switch statement mixed with lambdas, I'll try to provide an example.

```
...
Base* ptr = some_argument;
// Here we need the underlying type, so we'll do a match
Match(ptr)
{
    Case(A* a)
    {
        // this is invoked if ptr happened to hold an A, now do something A specific.
    }
    Case(B* b)
    {
        // this is invoked if ptr happened to hold a B, now do something B specific
    }
    Otherwise()
    {
        // this is invoked whenever none of the above are
    }
}
EndMatch;
...
```

This is an alternative to the usual solution, which is virtual pointers in the base class, and overriding. Note that type matching is commonly used in functional languages. For C++ there's a cleaver solution to achieving this, by Yuriy Solodkyy one of Bjarne Stroustrup's PhD students.

The short introductury paper can be found here;

https://parasol.tamu.edu/~yuriys/papers/OPM13EA.pdf

For a more information, check out hvis paper, which was presented to the ISO comitee; Open and Efﬁcient Type Switch for C++ by Stroustup, Dos Reis and Solodkyy

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3449.pdf

For the source code behind these papers goto Yuriys homepage at;

https://parasol.tamu.edu/~yuriys/pm/

If the number of classes you've got is truly closed, then consider using closed algebraic data types, as with `boost::variant`.These are have a few advantages over the unrestricted open algebraic data types, in that the compiler can usually ensure exhaustive matching, and in that the closed nature allows for more optimized pattern matching implementations, though at the cost of flexibility.

Also do note that `boost::variant` works nicely on C++03!

Do however please consider if you really need pattern matching or polymorphic dispatching. Both approaches are advantages and downsides, the main advance of the pattern matching approach, is that you aren't required to change your classes, and that you avoid polluting your base class with ultra specific virtual methods, which may only be called in a single location.